# Is there a not equal to in regex instead of not contains?

Tags: python, regex

So I have this simple regular expression here:

```
([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)
```

However, I want it to not capture it if it equals a specific word, so I found a workaround like this, where it should not contain this:

```
([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)?\b(?<!this)
```

Which is fine in retrospect, but if I have the instance where I have a word like this_that, it won't capture it because THIS is inside of that word, however, I want it to capture it unless it equals EXACTLY this and nothing else, make sense?

I did some research and I could not find a NOT operator in regex, just negative look aheads. Anyone have any ideas?

Lots of stuff, as stated above.

Comment: See https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick

Comment: Put `^` and `$` in the negative lookbehind, so it only matches the entire string.

Comment: just use a string equal comparison first then, why does that require a regexp?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture words unless the word is **this** you can do:

```
\bthis\b|(\w+)  # or [a-zA-Z_0-9]+ for ASCII only
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cHWMDx/1)

Alternatively, you can do:

```
\b(?!this\b)\w+ # or [a-zA-Z_0-9]+ for ASCII only
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/45Uv1l/1)

---

BTW: `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` is the same as `\w` in PCRE, Ruby, Java, ECMA, and other re flavors where `\w` is a shortcut for legal variable names in many computer languages.

*But* `\w` matches `àbç` in Python, Rust, C#, and others where the Unicode sense of a letter is used.

Comment: Nitpick: In modern Python, `\w` is default Unicode friendly, so it will capture non-ASCII alphabetic characters, where the explicit character class will not. They're only equivalent when working with `bytes` patterns, or when the `re.A`/`re.ASCII` flag modifies the regex.

Comment: Further nitpick: Python's implementation of `\w` is very different from that of Unicode's definition of `\w` and does not recognise many word forming characters. For more conformant Unicode definition of `\w` you need to use the `regex` module instead of `re`.